# Can an array in C be defined to adjust according to the inputs of the user?

Tags: c, arrays, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, num[10], termnum = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to calculate average and accept numbers from the user.
I want to store the index to use the info for other uses.
So the user can put numbers until "-1" and then it stops.
Can I make the array adjust ?

for example `int num[i],i=0;`?

Comment: You don't have to store the numbers if you want to calculate an average.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Variable Length Arrays if you know the array size is known at runtime and is reasonably small.

```
size_t len;
scanf("%zu", &len);
int arr[len];
```

The problem with VLAs is that the allocation failure can't be caught. For example, if `len` is very big then `arr` allocation might fail and you won't know it until it blows up. Besides, VLA support is optional since C11.

But if you want to continuously input numbers without knowing the total numbers then you can use dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` and `realloc()` as necessary:

```
size_t n = 16; //arbitrary start size
int *arr = arr(n * sizeof *arr);

while(..) {
  //read input here
  // realloc "arr" if number of inputs go beyond "n"
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't need the numbers but interested only in the average, then you don't need any array at all. Just read the numbers and calculate the total as you read:

```
int total = 0;
int num = 0;
size_t n = 0;

  while(scanf("%d", &num) == 1) && num != -1) {
     total += num; // need to take care of integer overflow!
     n++;
  }
```

Comment: A basic question and a golden answer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays (including variable-length arrays) cannot be resized after they have been defined.

If you want storage that can grow or shrink as necessary, you will have to allocate it dynamically with one of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, and then resize it using `realloc`:

```
int *arr;
size_t arrSize = 10;   // current size of array
size_t itemsRead = 0;  // number of elements stored so far

/**
 * Initially set aside space to store 10 integers
 */
arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * arrSize );
...
int item;
while ( scanf( "%d", &item ) == 1 && item != -1 )
{
  if ( itemsRead == arrSize )
  {
    int *tmp = realloc( arr, sizeof *arr * (arrSize * 2) );
    if ( tmp )
    {
      arr = tmp; 
      arrSize *= 2;
    }
    else
    {
      // could not extend storage, handle as necessary
    }
  }
  arr[itemsRead++] = item;
}
```

Doubling storage each time is a common technique; it minimizes the number of `realloc` calls (which can be expensive).  If you wanted to, you could extend by a fixed amount each time.

`realloc` will return `NULL` if it cannot satisfy the request, so you should  store the result to a temporary variable; otherwise you risk losing your reference to memory that's already been allocated, leading to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple man. If you use the `malloc` function passing as argument `lenght*sizeof(//type)` , you can get the space you need in HEAP memory. `malloc` returns a pointer to the beginning of the allocated memory.

```
int length;
int *pointer;
//read the length

pointer=malloc(length * sizeof(int));
```

The pointer is returned in void, so you need to make a cast to the type you need.